# flash player compile-time constant

Tags: flash, movieclip, flash-cs3

my program in flash cs3 won't run it keeps saying compiler-time constant

my program is this

```
maze_mc.buttonMode = true;
apple_mc.buttonMode = true;strong text
banana_mc.buttonMode = true;
var yes:Number = 9;

maze_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hint);

function hint(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    yes --
    yesTotal.text = String(yes)
}

banana_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, wint);

function wint(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    upd_txt.text = "you start here"
}

apple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, jint);

function jint(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    upd_txt.text = "click to win"
}

apple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ick);

function ick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    upd_txt.text = "you win"
}
```

can you please tell me where I went wrong
I have no clue where to wrap up my program.
It tells me that my items are a compile-time constant

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to end code statements with a semicolon. That may be part of the problem. For example (lines 10-11):

```
yes --;
yesTotal.text = String(yes);
```

instead of:

```
yes --
yesTotal.text = String(yes)
```

Flash compiles those two lines as a single statement when you leave out the semicolons at the end. You may often omit semicolons, but it is a good habit to use semicolons in your code.